# Kafka Server crashing when confluent KSQL is used in a Windows 10 Linux Subsystem

Tags: apache-kafka, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, confluent-platform

When i am using confluent ksql to create a stream and after resetting the offeset to earliest and trying to query the stream i am seeing the Kafka server crashing. I am using windows 10 and i have tried both Ubuntu and Debian as WSL.

I have tried to clear the log folder ***sudo rm -fr /tmp/confl**** and tried to restart the confluent platform using confluent local start but kafka is not getting started.

Below is the error i am seeing in the ***confluent local log kafka***

```
INFO [Transaction State Manager 0]: Loading transaction metadata from __transaction_state-8 at epoch 0 (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionStateManager)
[2020-06-26 11:27:26,208] **ERROR Error while renaming dir for _confluent-ksql-default_transient_1143297338875599674_1593157827320-Aggregate-Aggregate-Materialize-changelog-0 in log dir /tmp/confluent.HBnj6u7x/kafka/data (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /tmp/confluent.HBnj6u7x/kafka/data/_confluent-ksql-default_transient_1143297338875599674_1593157827320-Aggregate-Aggregate-Materialize-changelog-0 -> /tmp/confluent.HBnj6u7x/kafka/data/_confluent-ksql-default_transient_1143297338875599674_1593157827320-Aggregate-Aggregate-Materialize-changelog-0.355fe6c61afa41609e74e252e3dbac92-delete**


[2020-06-26 11:27:26,287] WARN Stopping serving logs in dir /tmp/confluent.HBnj6u7x/kafka/data (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2020-06-26 11:27:26,292] **ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in /tmp/confluent.HBnj6u7x/kafka/data have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)**
[2020-06-26 11:27:26,294] INFO [Transaction State Manager 0]: Completed loading transaction metadata from __transaction_state-44 for coordinator epoch 0 (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionStateManager)
[2020-06-26 11:27:26,295] INFO [Transaction State Manager 0]: Loading transaction metadata from __transaction_state-27 at epoch 0 (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionStateManager)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` error message tells me that something is off regarding KSQL being able to read/write files in the filesystem provided by WSL. This might be related to a common problem of WSL not providing the proper Linux permissions on the filesystem. A possible fix is describe [on this blog](https://www.turek.dev/post/fix-wsl-file-permissions/).

Regardless, I would encourage you to try using ksqlDB (the community version of Confluent KSQL) that provides ready-to-be-used scripts based on Docker so you can abstract away these filesystem problems and jump straight to the coding part.

[ksqlDB Quickstart](https://ksqldb.io/quickstart.html)